content script won't receive background script message
I'm trying to send the "executeAction" message from my background script to my content script that is supposed to listen for it.
I have put console.log messages everywhere to see what was causing the problem:
(background.js)
console.log('Background script running');
let actionStep = 0;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, _sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === 'actionCompleted') {
        actionStep++;
        triggerAction(tabId);
        console.log('Action completed');
    }
    else if (message.action === 'triggerAction') {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://www.amazon.com' }, (newTab) => {
            console.log('New tab created:', newTab);
            // Use the onUpdated listener to check when the tab has finished loading
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
                // Make sure the loaded tab is the new tab and it is complete
                console.log('TAB ID: ', tabId);
                if (tabId === newTab.id && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                    // Remove the listener to avoid unwanted multiple injections
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
                    // Execute the content script
                    console.log('ABOUT TO EXECUTE SCRIPT');
                    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        target: { tabId: newTab.id },
                        files: ['content.js']
                    
                    }, () => {
                        console.log('Content script injected');
                        triggerAction(tabId);
                    }
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    }
});


// Handle extension installation or updates
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    console.log('Extension installed or updated');
    // Perform any setup needed here, such as setting default storage values
});

// Modify the triggerAction function to accept newTab as a parameter
function triggerAction(newTab) {
    console.log('Triggering action number: ', actionStep);
    // Execute the content script before sending the message
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: newTab.id },
        files: ['content.js']
    }, () => {
        console.log('Content script injected');
        // Delay the message sending to ensure content script is ready
        // setTimeout(() => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, { action: 'executeAction', actionStep: actionStep });
            console.log('Message sent to content script');
        // }, 1000); // Adjust timing as needed
    });
    
}


In my console, the following message doesn't appear : 'Message sent to content script'.
Here is my listener on my content.js:
(content.js)
console.log('Content script loaded');


async function waitForSelector(selector) {
    console.log(`Waiting for selector: ${selector}`);
    while (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // check every 100ms
    }
}

async function performAction(action) {
    console.log('Performing action:', action);
    try {
        console.log(`Attempting to perform action: ${action.type} on selector: ${action.selector}`);
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'type':
                await waitForSelector(action.selector);
                const inputElement = document.querySelector(action.selector);
                inputElement.value = action.value;
                inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
                inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
                console.log('Type action performed.');
                break;
            case 'click':
                await waitForSelector(action.selector);
                document.querySelector(action.selector).click();
                console.log('Click action performed.');
                break;
            case 'scroll':
                await waitForSelector(action.selector);
                document.querySelector(action.selector).scrollIntoView();
                console.log('Scroll action performed.');
                break;
            case 'delay':
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, action.value));
                console.log(`Delay for ${action.value}ms`);
                break;
            default:
                console.error(`Unsupported action type: ${action.type}`);
                break;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error performing action:', error);
    }
}

const actions = [
    { type: 'type', selector: 'input#twotabsearchtextbox', value: 'The Pragmatic Programmer' },
    { type: 'click', selector: 'input.nav-input[type=submit]' }, // Submit button after typing
    { type: 'delay', value: 5000 }, // Delay to allow search results to load
    { type: 'click', selector: 'a.a-link-normal.s-underline-text.s-underline-link-text.s-link-style.a-text-normal' }, // Click on the first search result
    // { type: 'click', selector: 'li[id^="p_n_feature_twenty_browse-bin"] input[type="checkbox"]' }, // Click on the 'Kindle Unlimited Eligible' checkbox
    // { type: 'delay', value: 5000 }, // Delay to allow the product page to load
    // { type: 'click', selector: 'a#add-to-cart-button' }, // Click on the add to cart button
    // { type: 'delay', value: 5000 }, // Delay to allow the cart to update
    // { type: 'click', selector: 'a#hlb-view-cart-announce' } // Click on the cart button
];
async function executeAction(actionStep) {
    console.log('Executing action:', actionStep);
    // Retrieve the last action index from the URL hash if available

    performAction(actions[actionStep]);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'actionCompleted' });
    console.log('All actions executed.');
}


// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, _sendResponse) => {
        console.log('Received message');
        if (message.action === 'executeAction') {
            console.log('Received message to execute action: ', message.actionStep);
            executeAction(message.actionStep);
        }
    });
// });

I tried to put an executeScript to make sure that content.js was active when sending the message.

Remove the entire document.addEventListener line. Your script already runs after DOM is loaded.

Thanks for your answer. I tried to remove the line as you said but it didn't change the outcome.

Also replace chrome.runtime.sendMessage with chrome.tabs.sendMessage.

Ok. I tried that. But still nothing new in my console.

Reload the extension in chrome://extensions after editing the background script or content script.

I think I'm already doing that too.

There are no other problems with the posted code, so I guess there's something in the code that's not shown in the question or it's a timing bug in Chrome, in which case you can try delaying sendMessage by using setTimeout.

I have just edited the question so that you can have a wider view of my code.

You call triggerAction(tabId) where tabId is a number but this function expects a tab object, so triggerAction calls executeScript but with an invalid tabId: undefined, which fails immediately, so the callback is not executed. Looking at the code I guess you should remove executeScript inside onUpdated and just call triggerAction. Also replace newTab.id with newTab and rename it to tabId.
